# Will Varsol eventually evaporate from my deck boards so I that deck sealer will bond well?

Tags: deck, repainting

I am finally about to repaint my 20 year old deck with [Restore](https://www.rustoleum.ca/product-catalog/consumer-brands/restore/deck-and-concrete-10x). This project has gone on for far too many days already and I think it would have been easier (and cheaper if you count my time) to simply replace with all new deck boards.

Anyway, I have followed their preparation instructions (sanding, stripping, brushing, power washing) but I am still not confident that all areas pass their "splash test" requirement (water quickly absorbs rather than puddles). At one point I goofed and used [Varsol](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/varsol-3-78-l-0491005p.html#srp) on a small area to remove one of the industrial gel strippers I used.

Will the varsol simply evaporate with more time, or do I need to strip again?

At this point I'm almost ready to just roll the dice with what I've got, even if it means a less-then-ideal paint adhesion. My weather window is closing fast.

Any tips or advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is "Varsol" simply an alias for mineral spirits? If not, maybe link to the actual product.